# Rename las files with Python

Tags: python, lidar, las

I have a bunch of LAS files that have been delivered with different naming conventions.
I want to rename the files to all have the same uniform naming - based on the easting and northing coordinates of each tiles centroid.
I have generated a text file with the old and new names, and am trying to piece together a python script - but am running into this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\LASTools\Test\ReName_Files.py", line 64, in <module>
    newName = newList[indexOldName]
NameError: name 'indexOldName' is not defined
```

Here's the script. I am very new to Python and so this could take me hours of research and trial and error (it already has).

```
import os    
folder = "C:\LASTools\Test\\"    
lookupTable = open(folder + "LookupTable.txt")
tableList = lookupTable.readlines()
lookupTable.close()

old = "TIFF"
new = "TILE"

newTable = []
for line in tableList:
     newLine = line.strip()  
     newerLine = newLine.strip(",")  
     newestLine = newerLine.strip("'")   
     almostFinalLine = newestLine.replace('"',"")  
     finalLine = almostFinalLine.split(",")
     newTable.append(finalLine)

header = newTable[0]
indexOld = header.index(old) - 1
indexNew = header.index(new) - 1

oldList = []
newList = []
for item in newTable:
    if item != newTable[0]:
        valueOld = item[indexOld]
        valueNew = item[indexNew]
        oldList.append(valueOld)
        newList.append(valueNew)

for file in os.listdir(folder):
    nameAndExt = os.path.splitext(file)
    oldName = nameAndExt[0]
    extension = nameAndExt[1]
    print oldName

if oldName in oldList:
    indexOldName = oldList.index(oldName)

newName = newList[indexOldName]

os.rename(folder + oldName + extension, folder + newName + extension)
```

Comment: I don't really know how this is related to GIS as all you want to do is renaming files with a script. Better ask that on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Curlew, this is not a GIS question... however, you are using LasTools (it appears, you're not importing it!) which is a GIS lib.

Here's some code that might help - note it's in Esri arcpy objects but the Laspy you can use as a reference:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages')
import os, string, laspy, arcpy
from laspy.file import File

if len(sys.argv) != 5:
    print "Not enough arguments!"
    sys.exit()

InFolder = sys.argv[1]
OutFolder = sys.argv[2]
OutCoSys = sys.argv[3]
IndexName = sys.argv[4]

if not os.path.exists(InFolder):
    print "In folder not found"
    sys.exit()
if not os.path.exists(OutFolder):
    print "Out folder not found"
    sys.exit()

OutShape = "%s\\%s.shp" % (OutFolder,IndexName)

if os.path.exists(OutShape):
    try:
        print "Removing old index"
        arcpy.Delete_management(OutShape)
    except:
        print "Unable to remove, please check for write"
        print "access and permissions"
        sys.exit()

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(OutFolder,IndexName + ".shp","POLYGON","","DISABLED","DISABLED",OutCoSys)
arcpy.AddField_management(OutShape,"FileName","TEXT","","","125")
InsCur = arcpy.InsertCursor(OutShape,OutCoSys)

for ThisFile in os.listdir(InFolder):
    FileName,Ext = os.path.splitext(ThisFile)
    if Ext.lower() == ".las":
        LasOpened = False
        try:
            LASfile = File(InFolder + "\\" + ThisFile,mode = 'r')
            # This is the bit you should get interested in
            # The MinCo and MaxCo is a list/tuple in the order [[X],[Y]]
            MinCo = LASfile.header.get_min()
            MaxCo = LASfile.header.get_max()
            # the centroid is then
            # CenX = (MinCo[0] + MaxCo[0]) / 2
            # CenY = (MinCo[1] + MaxCo[1]) / 2
            # Make your file name from that and then use
            # os.rename(InFolder + "\\" + ThisFile,InFolder + "\\" + NewName) # to rename
            LASfile.close()
            LasOpened = True
        except:
            print "Unable to open %s with LasPY" % ThisFile
        if LasOpened:
            Xmin = int( MinCo[0] / 1000) * 1000
            Ymin = int( MinCo[1] / 1000) * 1000
            Xmax = (int( MaxCo[0] / 1000) * 1000) + 1000#Xmin + 1000#int( MaxCo[0] / 1000) * 1000#Xmin + 1000
            Ymax = (int( MaxCo[1] / 1000) * 1000) + 1000#Ymin + 1000#int( MaxCo[1] / 1000) * 1000#Ymin + 1000
            Xmin = MinCo[0]
            Ymin = MinCo[1]
            Xmax = MaxCo[0]
            Ymax = MaxCo[1]
            PArray = arcpy.Array()
            NewPol = InsCur.newRow()
            TPnt = arcpy.Point(Xmin,Ymin)
            PArray.add(TPnt)
            TPnt = arcpy.Point(Xmin,Ymax)
            PArray.add(TPnt)
            TPnt = arcpy.Point(Xmax,Ymax)
            PArray.add(TPnt)
            TPnt = arcpy.Point(Xmax,Ymin)
            PArray.add(TPnt)
            TPnt = arcpy.Point(Xmin,Ymin)
            PArray.add(TPnt)
            Poly = arcpy.Polygon(PArray,OutCoSys)
            NewPol.shape = Poly
            NewPol.setValue("FileName",ThisFile)
            InsCur.insertRow(NewPol)
            del PArray
            del NewPol
del InsCur
```

I've put some comments in there to direct your attention. For users of Esri this is a good way to get a shapefile of your coverage of LAS files. Note, I wrote this prior to 10.1 with the LASdataset so it's mostly redundant.

Answer (score 2):

```
if oldName in oldList:
    indexOldName = oldList.index(oldName)
newName = newList[indexOldName]
```

The problem is when `oldName` is never in `oldList` then `indexOldName` never gets set to anything (defined), and the error is generated.

Make sure oldName is really in oldList, and set to `indexOldName` something, such as:

```
if oldName in oldList:
    indexOldName = oldList.index(oldName)
else:
    indexOldName = 0
newName = newList[indexOldName]
```